# Date Serialization in WCF Rest Service

Tags: json, datetime, wcf-rest

Im using C# and I have  the following LINQ statement

```
var WeeklySalesQuery = from d in db.DashboardFigures
                                 join s in outlets.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)) on d.OutletNo equals s
                                 where (d.TypeOfinformation == "SALES-TW")
                                 group d by new
                                 {
                                     d.TypeOfinformation,
                                     d.Date
                                 } into newGroupedresult
                                 select new Weeklysales()
                                 {
                                     dt = ((DateTime)newGroupedresult.Key.Date),
                                     Sv = (double)newGroupedresult.Sum(d => d.Value_1) + (double)newGroupedresult.Sum(d => d.Value_2),
                                     KPI = 1
                                 };
```

However, the format of dt that is coming out is

```
"\/Date(1421884800000+0000)\/
```

I have tried Changing the code to

```
dt = ((DateTime)newGroupedresult.Key.Date).ToString("dd.mm.yyyy")
```

bit I get build errors telling me I cannot convert a string into DateTime format.

Comment: You have ms format of json datetime. Look herer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969757/parsing-a-json-date-info-into-a-c-sharp-datetime
What is the type of newGroupedresult.Key.Date?

Comment: *Dates don't have formats*. The error means that your database column contains strings, not dates. The *string's* format suggest it was inserted from a Json string, one that uses the old DataContractJsonSerializer. JSon doesn't have a date type but convention nowadays is to use the ISO 8601 format

Comment: If `Key.Date` is a string the you have to do sth like `DateTime.Parse(newGroupedresult.Key.Date)` instead of casting.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos this won't work nor is it a solution. The old Json format isn't recognisable by DateTime.Parse or ParseExact.

Comment: The real solution is to 1) add a new datetime or datetimeoffset field to hold dates 2) parse the old Json data and store the dates in the new field 3) Remove the old field and rename the new one to the old one's name

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. im not 100% sure how to do this. Are you saying that i create a new field?, with what data type ?

Comment: Alpesh, can you clarify `the format of dt that is coming out`? @PanagiotisKanavos thinks you mean the value coming out of the database, I think you mean you are serialising `Weeklysales` somewhere.

Comment: @Rawling  public DateTime dt { get; set; }   this is for a web service call. returning the result in JSON format

Comment: So with your original code, everything builds and runs, but the JSON out of your web service call looks wrong? Sounds like your JSON serialiser then.

Comment: @Rawling, OK this is my first web service with Json, what exactly does that mean, do I need to do some sort of conversation?. This web service is going to be used by IOS and Android devices, is it best to keep the Json format or convert to traditional date format

Comment: @Alpesh then this question has nothing to do with LINQ. It's about serializing dates in a WCF REST service. The code you posted isn't relevant, the conversion happens elsewhere.

Comment: @Rawling. OK, like I said, new to me, sorry

Comment: Please post the code of the WeeklySales class. Serialization is controlled by the attributes placed on this class. If it's a new service though, it's far easier to use ASP.NET Web API. It's built specifically to create REST services, doesn't include any legacy baggage (like the date serialization) and is much faster, partly because it uses a modern Json serializer

Comment: (@Alpesh No need to apologise to me, that wasn't me :p)

Answer (score 1):

As this is a new REST service, the best option is to abandon WCF and create use [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) to create REST services. WCF Rest services were a stop-gap measure that carry a lot of legacy baggage. One of them is the largely abandoned and slow serializer they use.

While it *is* possible to change the serializer it isn't trivial. The process is described in [Supporting different data and serialization formats in WCF](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Supporting-different-data-b0351c9a) by Carlos Figueira and it's definitely not for beginners.

The code you posted suggests you are trying to create a REST service to support a BI dashboard. In this case you should also consider [OData](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api) on top of Web API. OData exposes a REST service over data entities and allows clients to specify queries using URL query parameters like filter, select, group etc.

This will allow your clients to specify the criteria and columns they want in the URL without requiring modifications to your service code. OData works on top of IQueryable so the query that is finally executed only pulls the data the client wants from the database.

Visual Studio has wizards that allow you to easily expose OData services from any Entity Framework model, although OData isn't limited to only EF.

Clients can create query URLs directly or they can use the proxies generated by Visual Studio to work with LINQ syntax, or the javascript client libraries.

Finally, you don't need to worry about clients making weird requests that will kill the database. You can expose specific queries only as methods, or apply your own restrictions on the IQueryable that will be exposed.

It's also very easy to add caching support, making operations like revisiting the same page while paging or viewing different dashboard pages, very cheap. Doing this with WCF is non-trivial.

**PS:** Excel can also read data from OData services. Should stop analysts and financial managers from demanding access to the database.

A good blow-by-blow tutorial is [Create an OData v4 Endpoint Using ASP.NET Web API 2.2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint)